# Visual Studio 2017 15.7 New Chrome Window when debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Just updated to 15.7 and now when I begin debugging Chrome opens in new window.

My JS debugging is off (tried turning it on and back off) and unlike when it's on the new window is under my standard Chrome profile. However If I snap the chrome window into my other window debugging ends immediately.

Any ideas on how to correct this?

Comment: Fixed 5 hours ago: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/234160/disable-js-debug-but-open-new-chrome-window.html

Comment: Strange. Says I should have a new update notification? I do not. Tried checking in the installer as well.

Comment: Only the programmers are agile, delivery of their bug fixes is not.  You'll have to wait until they push the bugfix out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments from Hans about posted fix in the Pre-release version that has yet to be released.

My workaround, because the debugger would randomly stop when using the new window, was to set the project to not open a webpage and then open the site via the IIS icon in the taskbar.

Answer (score 48):

In Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7.1 you can do the following:

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Web Projects, uncheck Stop debugger when browser window is closed.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Didn't realise this was a new option. Thanks, this worked for me.

Comment: This option is at the same location for Visual Studio 2019 version 16.1.0

Comment: This option is at the same location for Visual Studio 2022 version 17.0.4

Answer (score -1):

You can disable it by following these steps inside Debug -> Options ->Debugging->General->Enable JavaScript debugging for ASP.NET(Chrome and IE) you can disable it.
[image]